# How can I get RVM working w/ gems on Ubuntu 16.04 for local users?

Tags: ruby, ubuntu, rubygems, rvm

I'm running ubuntu 16.04 desktop, and attempting to get RVM working so that I can:

- Have the latest stable version of ruby installed and usable.
- Install Ruby gems when necessary WITHOUT SUDO permissions.

To this end, here's what I've done:

Installed RVM as explained on the official RVM site: https://rvm.io/

```
# This keyserver can't be found, btw. So this bit doesn't work.
$ gpg --keyserver hkp://keys.gnupg.net --recv-keys 409B6B1796C275462A1703113804BB82D39DC0E3

gpg: requesting key D39DC0E3 from hkp server keys.gnupg.net
?: keys.gnupg.net: Host not found
gpgkeys: HTTP fetch error 7: couldn't connect: Success
gpg: no valid OpenPGP data found.
gpg: Total number processed: 0
gpg: keyserver communications error: keyserver unreachable
gpg: keyserver communications error: public key not found
gpg: keyserver receive failed: public key not found

# Install RVM w/ ruby.
$ \curl -sSL https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable --ruby

Downloading https://github.com/rvm/rvm/archive/1.27.0.tar.gz
Downloading https://github.com/rvm/rvm/releases/download/1.27.0/1.27.0.tar.gz.asc
gpg: Signature made Tue 29 Mar 2016 06:49:47 AM PDT using RSA key ID BF04FF17
gpg: Good signature from "Michal Papis (RVM signing) <mpapis@gmail.com>" [unknown]
gpg: WARNING: This key is not certified with a trusted signature!
gpg:          There is no indication that the signature belongs to the owner.
Primary key fingerprint: 409B 6B17 96C2 7546 2A17  0311 3804 BB82 D39D C0E3
     Subkey fingerprint: 62C9 E5F4 DA30 0D94 AC36  166B E206 C29F BF04 FF17
GPG verified '/home/rdegges/.rvm/archives/rvm-1.27.0.tgz'

Upgrading the RVM installation in /home/rdegges/.rvm/
    RVM PATH line found in /home/rdegges/.zshrc.
    RVM PATH line not found for Bash, rerun this command with '--auto-dotfiles' flag to fix it.
    RVM sourcing line found in /home/rdegges/.zshrc.
    RVM sourcing line not found for Bash, rerun this command with '--auto-dotfiles' flag to fix it.
Upgrade of RVM in /home/rdegges/.rvm/ is complete.

# Randall Degges,
#
#   Thank you for using RVM!
#   We sincerely hope that RVM helps to make your life easier and more enjoyable!!!
#
# ~Wayne, Michal & team.

In case of problems: https://rvm.io/help and https://twitter.com/rvm_io

Upgrade Notes:

  * No new notes to display.

rvm 1.27.0 (latest) by Wayne E. Seguin <wayneeseguin@gmail.com>, Michal Papis <mpapis@gmail.com> [https://rvm.io/]
Already installed ruby-2.3.0.
To reinstall use:

    rvm reinstall ruby-2.3.0

Creating alias default for ruby-2.3.0....

  * To start using RVM you need to run `source /home/rdegges/.rvm/scripts/rvm`
    in all your open shell windows, in rare cases you need to reopen all shell windows.
```

At this point, even though the GPG keys couldn't be imported, I am able to install RVM / Ruby succesfully it seems.

I've then sourced the RVM file, by including the following snippet in my `~/.zshrc` file:

```
PATH=$PATH:$HOME/.rvm/bin
[[ -s "~/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && source "~/.rvm/scripts/rvm"
```

This works well, and I can confirm this by echo'ing my $PATH, eg:

```
$ echo $PATH
...:/home/rdegges/.rvm/bin
```

Finally, if I use rvm to output the list of installed ruby versions, I see ruby installed:

```
$ rvm list
rvm rubies

=* ruby-2.3.0 [ x86_64 ]

# => - current
# =* - current && default
#  * - default
```

This makes it look as if I've got ruby 2.3.0 installed and default.

Here's where things get weird...

If I say `which ruby`, I get:

```
$ which ruby
/usr/bin/ruby
```

I would expect to see my ruby version being pulled from `~/.rvm`.

Secondly, when I attempt to install any gem, for instance: `travis`, I get the following permission errors:

```
$ gem install travis
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::FilePermissionError)
    You don't have write permissions for the /var/lib/gems/2.3.0 directory.
```

Obviously, this is not the way things are supposed to work. RVM is supposed to install ruby locally for my user so that I can install gems and use different versions of ruby WITHOUT needing to overwrite system files and packages.

I must be doing something wrong, but I've spent several hours scouring stackoverflow, the official rvm documentation, etc., and haven't found a solution.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Try running `/bin/bash --login` before installing the gem, or configure your terminal to use "login shell". If this is proving difficult to solve, rbenv is an option as well.

Comment: I'm using the login shell already for my terminal =/ Never tried rbenv yet. Maybe I should just give that a go :(